# Termination of program upon exit

Tags: python, exit, python-idle

I am not sure whether I can formulate my question right because I am a beginner but I will give it a try.

I have a Python program which uses .pyw extension and upon killing the program in IDLE it still shows up in my task manager and so I have to extra end the task manually in there to clean up for a new re-run. I am not sure which tools to use to tell the .pyw program to kill itself and all its pieces upon exit. I thought about adding the following line of code at the end of the program but it doesn't seem to work (I am pretty sure the logic is faulty):

```
if sys.exit() == True:
    os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM pythonw.exe')
```

How to go about this issue? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I presume you are using Windows ('task manager'), but what versions of Windows and Python?  What do you start and how?  What does 'killing the program in IDLE' mean?

Comment: W10, Python 2.7.13. I have a logging system that is recording key presses in a text file. I have first defined a key press event and then used with-as statement to record logs in file. By killing the program in IDLE (or Shell) I mean just closing it by exiting Python Shell. Hope that helps to answer some of your questions.

Comment: Did you load the file into an IDLE editor and run it with F5?  Before you exit, has the program stopped, as indicated by the reappearance of `>>>` after the RESTART line?  What happens if you run from command line instead?

Comment: When 2.7 IDLE starts from icon, there should be pythonw.exe under Apps (the Shell) and Background processes (the user execution process).  Load file in editor and you should see (2) (2 windows) after Apps entry.  If you close Shell, pythonw.exe should be left under Apps until you close editor.

Answer (score 0):

This is a build-in libary https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html

```
import os, sys, atexit
def ex():
    os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM pythonw.exe')

atexit.register(ex)
```

Comment: Tried your method, unfortunately it didn't solve the issue. Pythonw program sits still in task manager after exiting IDLE.

Comment: look for the ending. is it really .exe?

Comment: Yes, it is. The strange thing I noticed is that once I run the program it creates two instances of Pythonw - one is closable with simple exiting from Python Shell and other one has to be manually deleted in task manager. The latter one is the root problem I am trying to solve.